# Oracle SQL Joins error "table or view does not exist"

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting an error that the table does not exist. I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong though.

This is what I need to produce: /*1. List the full name (first and last name) and phone number for students that live in Newark, NJ.
Sort on last name and first name.*/

[image: Database Schema]

```
   SELECT s.first_name,s.last_name, s.zip, z.state, z.city
   FROM student s JOIN zip z
   ON s.zip=z.zip
   and z.city='Newark' and z.state='NJ'
   ORDER BY s.last_name, s.first_name;
```

Comment: Your error message is very clear. Your database schema only has table `zipcode`, no table name's `zip`.

Answer (score 0):

Run the query belown to see the tables `student` and `zip` are found in the list of tables in your schema:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME 
  FROM DBA_OBJECTS
 WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
   AND OWNER = '[your database schema name]';
```

Or to do a quick verification run this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME 
  FROM DBA_OBJECTS
 WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' AND LOWER(OBJECT_NAME) IN ('student','zip')
   AND OWNER = '[your database schema name]';
```

If you don't see the table names in neither of the results of the queries above, then you have to see the database admin to grant you the appropriate privilege on the schema, or create the tables if they don't really exist.